# What is the English term for 「制度管治」?

Tags: translation

I've been searching on the internet but cannot find anything relevant. Should it be "governance by systems", "system governance" or something else? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It could mean `制度的管治` or `regulatory management`.

Answer (score 0):

Rule/govern by (the) system.  But usually it is noun. So what you found out is correct.  这个国家施行制度管制。 Forget about language, it's a joke.  Chinese always line up the priority: 情-理-法，which is much more human.

Comment: So should the noun be "governance by (the) system"? Or should it be "system governance" ? Thank you.

Comment: Very fundamental question:  similar case "a lady of beauty" vs "a beautiful lady".